# View_by_Course_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'course_code_and_name'

Tags: html, django

I have used Django to develop a web app.
When I tried to pass a string in the url, error occurs: View_by_Course_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'course_code_and_name'

view.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def View_by_Course_list(request, course_code_and_name):
if request.method == 'POST':
...
```

url.py:

```
path('View_by_Course_list/$',views.View_by_Course_list, name='View_by_Course_list'),
```

HTML:

```
<a href="{% url 'bms:View_by_Course_list' %}?course_code_and_name={{course_for_select}}" id=" {{course_for_select}}" onclick=""> {{course_for_select}}</a>
```

I got the error: k    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: View_by_Course_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'course_code_and_name'

How should I correct it?

Comment: Since you use a *query string*, you access this with `request.GET['course_code_and_name']`. You thus should remove that parameter from the function and use it with `request.GET` instead.

Comment: tried, failed, it's a a <a> value, not input value so could not use request.GET to fetch

Answer (score 0):

In url.py you should pass the course_code_and_name:

```
path('View_by_Course_list/<int:course_code_and_name>',views.View_by_Course_list, name='View_by_Course_list'),
```

also when you using url tag in django template, you need to pass the arguments:

```
href="{% url 'bms:View_by_Course_list' course_code_and_name=course_for_select %}"
```

Check refrences:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#example
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /check_discilpine/
Reverse for 'View_by_Course_list' with keyword arguments '{'course_for_select': <CourseInfo: Financial Accounting>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: